# Can my local host get attacked if I don't port forward?

Tags: networking, server, localhost, port-forwarding, hacking

Can my local host get attacked if I don't port forward?
I'm currently running a server which for a certain app, I'm having problems with passwords and decided that is easier if I leave them default, Can this leave me in a vulnerable spot even if I don't port forward?

Answer (score 0):

If you have zero ports forwarded through your firewall you should be safe from an internet based attack. If you forward ANY port you have a greater vulnerability. 
Having a default password is another vulnerability. What if someone gets on your wifi?

Ultimately, I'd REALLY recommended against it.

Comment: NAT is essentially port forwarding but only for handling active connections - standard web browsing can still put users at risk.